# UITableView does not update

Tags: json, swift, tableview

I have a `UITableView` that displays items from a JSON, however when I enter or change the screen and go back to it the items do not appear and the screen goes blank. I've already put the `reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad`, and I've tried putting it inside a `DispatchQueue`, but I'm not successful. Has anyone had it or do you know how to fix it?

In viewDidLoad():

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    AuthorizationUser()
    IndicadoresInicial()
    resetLists()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Methods TableView:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayUsers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 49
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.lblItens.text = self.arrayUsers[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgItens.image = UIImage(named: self.arrayImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellView.frame.height / 2
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It would be quite helpful

Comment: In viewDidLoad, I do the following: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        AuthorizationUser()
        IndicadoresInicial()
        resetLists()

Comment: @JuniorSanches Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48339578/edit) your question to add information / code rather than writing comments.

Comment: Where is the method that fetches the JSON?

Comment: Okay, I already added the code

Answer (score 3):

Without additional details it's quite difficult to understand what is going on.

First of all, if your controller is created once, you need to move `reloadData` method into another lifecycle method like `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. Then, you need to verify that `reloadData` is called in the main thread if the JSON is downloaded in background. Finally, be sure the data source for the table view has been set up correctly.

Are you able to provide more details?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, I do the following: DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() } AuthorizationUser() IndicadoresInicial() resetLists() –  I put the reloadData () inside a DispatchQueue to run first. I've also tried using the viewWillAppear with reloadData () inside, but I did not succeed

Comment: @JuniorSanches Please add the code to your question.